# How to generate uuid which will be the same for each seed string?

Tags: algorithm, uuid, boost-uuid

I am wondering how to get the same uuid by using the same seed string. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with boost-uuid, but I think that what you need is a name-based UUID generator (see [RFC-4122 Section 4.3](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)). Read that section of the RFC to ensure it fits your requirements.

Googling a bit, I found that boost does support [name-based UUIDs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/uuid/uuid.html#Name%20Generator):